# How get the number of documents firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

How i can get number of documents from firebase realtime database?
I find answers only for  firebase firestore.

Comment: its answer to firestore collection, i need realtime db

Comment: You can search for a combination of tags, so: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+count+number+of+children

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of your children in a Firebase Realtime Database, you have to use `getChildrenCount()` on a `DataSnapshot` object. I would recommend to read in the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#public-long-getchildrencount-) for more information.

[Here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Reading_Firebase_Realtime_Database_Data) is also an example on how to use it.

The following Code example is also from the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-start). It's a bit modified.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

// Attach a listener to print out the number of total children
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```